# Is there an equivalent to "née" (birth name) for an *ex*-spousal name?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, names, legalese, interpersonal-relations

When a woman marries she often is able to identify her former surname (aka *maiden name*) using the term [*née*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Given_name#Name_at_birth) (men can use *né* though it is less common).
If the woman later changes her name due to divorce or widowing/remarriage is there a term to use that would identify her former married name usage?

Example: In [this article](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/2015-08-23/time-crashers-meet-the-celebrities) **Meg Mathews** is identified as *"Famous for: being the former Mrs Noel Gallagher"*.

This means she has been able at various points in her life to use the following name forms:

- Meg Mathews
- Meg (née Mathews) Gallagher
- Meg Gallagher
- Mrs. Noel Gallagher
- Meg Mathews (formerly Mrs. Noel Gallagher)

What I am wondering is if there is an English (or for that matter non-English) term which she could be identified by such as (*this is hypothetical*):

- Meg (*prév* Gallagher) Mathews

I know this is **EL&U** but I am including in my request any applicable foreign terms since *née* is itself a foreign term adopted into English usage.

Comment: In my experience it's more commonly *Meg Gallagher (née Mathews)* unless she is using her maiden name as her middle name, in which case it's just *Meg Mathews Gallagher.*

Comment: The analogous adoption of a French word might be _mariée_.

Comment: @Joffan - You might be on to an idea there, but perhaps a more appropriate French word would be **passé** (which implies past/former). Use of **mariée** might be appropriate for a person who is *currently* married to someone who uses an asynchronous name.

Comment: I frankly doubt there are enough women who have been divorced who want to identify themselves by their former husbands' names to require such a word 8-).

Comment: @AlMaki - You are forgetting this could also apply to widows/widowers (of notable spouses) who may have remarried. Also it could sometimes be appropriate for a divorced person to use such a form when their children have the ex-spouse's last name and you are trying to clarify the relationship.

Comment: @OMY I'm saying I don't think there is such a word because I don't think there are many people who would use it. In my experience, the last thing divorced women want to do is identify with their former spouses, quite the contrary.  The only person I can think of who chooses to identify herself with her former spouse is Ivana Trump. (In fact, an interesting topic would be terms used to describe former spouses.)

Comment: @AlMaki -- Contrary to your experience there are many women who keep their married name after divorce. Reasons range from simple convenience (no need to get a new driver's license) to courtesy for any children (shows respect for their biological father and avoids questions like "Why is your mom's last name different than yours?") and sometimes because the marriage ended amiably so the name is not negatively charged. These circumstances also could apply to remarried widows/widowers just as much as divorcees. All of these situations are common enough to cause a potential need for such a word.

Comment: @O.M.Y. I was using _mariée_ by analogy with _née_, "as married", "as born", in both cases implicitly a past case because the current name is given.

Answer (score 3):

I've not heard one in common usage. "Meg Mathews (formerly Mrs. Noel Gallagher)" is how I'd expect to hear it. (Actually, I'd expect "Meg Mathews (formerly Gallagher)" as a shorthand.)

As changing names multiple times in life, or reverting to a maiden name after divorce is a more modern occurrence, we don't have an historical word stolen from some other language.

Answer (score 0):

I've got two suggestions:

> [FKA](http://www.acronymfinder.com/FKA.html)

"Formely known as"

Could be used for example in  **Meg  Matthews (FKA Galagher)**. It's common enough and close enough to AKA that most people would understand it, or remember once explained.

> EX

is also interesting because

1) [Someone's ex](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ex_1) is the person they used to be married to or used to have a romantic or sexual relationship with

and

2) [ex- as a prefix](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ex_2) is added to nouns to show that someone or something is no longer the thing referred to by that noun.

For example

> he's an ex-marine, ex-addict, ex-convict...she's an ex-Galagher (she does not belong to this family anymore)

Hence simply **Meg  Matthews (ex-Galagher)** or **Meg (ex-Galagher) Matthews*** if you want to indicate that she doesn't bear the name anymore.

I don't think anybody would get confused about the meaning or what you're talking about and it's the shortest and simplest word possible.